# Finding max value using reduce

Tags: clojure

New to clojure with a java background. I have the following table and need to transform the table to a hash-map that maps products to the city that has the highest sale. For example, the output should look like:

```
{"Pencil": "Toronto"
"Bread": "Ottawa"}

(def table [
    {:product "Pencil"
    :city "Toronto"
    :year "2010"
    :sales "2653.00"}
    {:product "Pencil"
    :city "Oshawa"
    :year "2010"
    :sales "525.00"}
    {:product "Bread"
    :city "Toronto"
    :year "2010"
    :sales "136,264.00"}
    {:product "Bread"
    :city "Oshawa"
    :year "nil"
    :sales "242,634.00"}
    {:product "Bread"
    :city "Ottawa"
    :year "2011"
    :sales "426,164.00"}])
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(reduce (fn [product-cities {:keys [product sales]}]
         (update-in product-cities [product] (fnil conj []) sales))
       {}
       table)
```

This produces the outcome:

```
{"Bread"
["136,264.00"
"242,634.00"
"426,164.00"],
 "Pencil" ["2653.00" "525.00"]}
```

How can i compare the sales of each city and and only keep the name of the city with the highest sales? Having a really tough time with this. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a handy function `max-key` in clojure.core, that is perfectly suitable for this case:

```
(defn process [table]
  (let [parseDouble #(Double/parseDouble (clojure.string/replace % #"," ""))]
    (->> table
         (group-by :product)
         (map (comp (juxt :product :city)
                    (partial apply max-key (comp parseDouble :sales))
                    val))
         (into {}))))

user> (process table)
;;=> {"Pencil" "Toronto", "Bread" "Ottawa"}
```

the key is that `(partial apply max-key (comp parseDouble :sales))` part looks for the record in a group, having maximum parsed sales value.

Comment: I would have written almost the same answer – the variation being that I now like to use `into` with a transducer as this avoids at least one level of laziness overhead. Like this: `(into {} (map (comp ,,,)) (group-by :product table))`.

Answer (score 3):

You need some function that will convert the sales values from strings to numbers. For now assuming the sales numbers are indeed numbers, this should do the trick:

```
(->> table
     (group-by :product)
     (map (fn [[k v]]
            [k (first (sort-by (comp - identity :sales) v))]))
     (into {})
     vals
     (map (comp #(apply vector %)
                vals
                #(select-keys % [:product :city])))
     (into {}))
```

Replace `identity` with your `string->number` function.

No doubt this function can be improved...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
(into {} (map (fn [[k {:keys [city sales]}]] [k city])
                (reduce (fn [product-cities {:keys [product sales city]}]
                          (let [sales (Double/parseDouble (clojure.string/replace sales "," ""))
                                prev-sales (get-in product-cities [product :sales] 0)]
                            (if (> sales prev-sales)
                              (assoc product-cities product {:sales sales :city city})
                              product-cities)))
                        {}
                        table)))
```

P.S. Although previous answer could be more readable...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty fast version that avoids intermediate data structures:

```
(let [parse #(Double/parseDouble (clojure.string/replace % "," ""))]
  (reduce (fn [m {:keys [product sales city] :as cand}]
            (let [sales-d (parse sales)]
              (update m product (fn [prev]
                                  (if (or (nil? prev) (< (:sales prev) sales-d))
                                    (assoc cand :sales sales-d) 
                                    prev)))))
          {} products))
```

Answer (score 0):

A spinoff idea based on @leetwinski answer.
Idea is to use sort-by on sales' values as it's a bit more basic in the language.

```
(defn process [table]
  (let [parseDouble #(Double/parseDouble (clojure.string/replace % #"," ""))
        parsedTable (for [a table] (update a :sales parseDouble))]
    (->> parsedTable
         (sort-by :sales)
         (group-by :product)
         vals        
         (map (comp (juxt :product :city) last))
         (into {}))))
 (process table)
=>{"Bread" "Ottawa" "Pencil" "Toronto"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do it.  I used `spyx-pretty` [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) to make visualizing the intermediate steps easier ([API docs can be found here](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/)).  The code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core
        tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]
            [clojure.string :as str] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def table
  [{:product "Pencil" :city "Toronto" :year "2010" :sales "2653.00"}
   {:product "Pencil" :city "Oshawa" :year "2010" :sales "525.00"}
   {:product "Bread" :city "Toronto" :year "2010" :sales "136,264.00"}
   {:product "Bread" :city "Oshawa" :year "nil" :sales "242,634.00"}
   {:product "Bread" :city "Ottawa" :year "2011" :sales "426,164.00"}])

(defn str->double
  "Convert a string like '2,123.97' to a double like 2123.97 "
  [str-val]
  (let [no-commas (str/replace str-val #"," "")
        dbl-val   (Double/parseDouble no-commas)]
    dbl-val))

(dotest
  (let [table-num (forv [item table]
                    (update item :sales str->double))
        grouped   (group-by :product table-num)
        >>        (spyx-pretty grouped)
        group-max (forv [group grouped]
                    (do
                      (spyx-pretty group)
                      (let [records        (xsecond group)
                            >>             (spyx-pretty records)
                            records-sorted (sort-by :sales > records)
                            >>             (spyx-pretty records-sorted)
                            max-rec        (xfirst records-sorted)
                            ]
                        (spyx max-rec))))]
    (spyx-pretty group-max)))
```

The results are:

```
---------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.9.0-beta1    Java 9.0.1
---------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

grouped => 
{"Pencil"
 [{:product "Pencil", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 2653.0}
  {:product "Pencil", :city "Oshawa", :year "2010", :sales 525.0}],
 "Bread"
 [{:product "Bread", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 136264.0}
  {:product "Bread", :city "Oshawa", :year "nil", :sales 242634.0}
  {:product "Bread", :city "Ottawa", :year "2011", :sales 426164.0}]}

group => 
["Pencil"
 [{:product "Pencil", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 2653.0}
  {:product "Pencil", :city "Oshawa", :year "2010", :sales 525.0}]]

records => 
[{:product "Pencil", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 2653.0}
 {:product "Pencil", :city "Oshawa", :year "2010", :sales 525.0}]

records-sorted => 
({:product "Pencil", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 2653.0}
 {:product "Pencil", :city "Oshawa", :year "2010", :sales 525.0})
max-rec => {:product "Pencil", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 2653.0}

group => 
["Bread"
 [{:product "Bread", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 136264.0}
  {:product "Bread", :city "Oshawa", :year "nil", :sales 242634.0}
  {:product "Bread", :city "Ottawa", :year "2011", :sales 426164.0}]]

records => 
[{:product "Bread", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 136264.0}
 {:product "Bread", :city "Oshawa", :year "nil", :sales 242634.0}
 {:product "Bread", :city "Ottawa", :year "2011", :sales 426164.0}]

records-sorted => 
({:product "Bread", :city "Ottawa", :year "2011", :sales 426164.0}
 {:product "Bread", :city "Oshawa", :year "nil", :sales 242634.0}
 {:product "Bread", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 136264.0})
max-rec => {:product "Bread", :city "Ottawa", :year "2011", :sales 426164.0}

group-max => 
[{:product "Pencil", :city "Toronto", :year "2010", :sales 2653.0}
 {:product "Bread", :city "Ottawa", :year "2011", :sales 426164.0}]
```

Note that the 1st step is to convert all string sales values to floating point. Then, it is easiest if we use the built-in function `group-by` to separate out pencils from Bread, etc.  I like to keep each step separate for ease of thinking, and also so I can put debug printouts at each step.

IMHO this is more straightforward than using the REPL, as I can stay in my favorite IDE/editor and the stuff I type is saved in a file rather than disappearing as soon as I hit .

Comment: I think if you are going to use non-core libraries then you should make it explicit in the code. `forv` is a tupelo function right? Why not `t/forv`? The only exception I can think of is `core.async`, which has some very funny function names that stand out.

Comment: My argument was about readability for others, rather than convenience for yourself.